# Isn't simple spin locking with atomic variables better than this "lock-free queue"?

Tags: c++, multithreading

At [this](https://jbseg.medium.com/lock-free-queues-e48de693654b) block the writer provides an example of a lock-free queue using a linked list. It seems to me that there are at least three atomic operations in the push method. Even disregarding the first one, where he creates the actual node, there are at least two atomic operations.

```
template<typename T>
class lock_free_queue
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        std::atomic<node*> next;
        node(T const& data_):
            data(std::make_shared<T>(data_))
        {}
    };
    std::atomic<node*> head;
    std::atomic<node*> tail;
public:
    void push(T const& data)
    {
        std::atomic<node*> const new_node=new node(data);
        node* old_tail = tail.load();
        while(!old_tail->next.compare_exchange_weak(nullptr, new_node)){
          node* old_tail = tail.load();
        }
        tail.compare_exchange_weak(old_tail, new_node);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
    {
        node* old_head=head.load();
        while(old_head &&
            !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head,old_head->next)){
            old_head=head.load();
        }
        return old_head ? old_head->data : std::shared_ptr<T>();
    }
};
```

My naive way of adding to a queue, or anything, would be to use an atomic flag with a test and set at the start, and then atomically setting the flag to false (unlocking) before leaving the function. This is two atomic operations and simpler than this example. Is the example given above on this block a good example?

The naive way is also simpler to understand, lock, do your stuff, and unlock, it took me a while to get what was happening above.

Comment: This article is suspiciously short (didn't read it yet). If you like to see some more trustworthy explanation how to use atomics see Herb Sutter talk on cpccon ["Lock-Free Programming (or, Juggling Razor Blades)"](https://youtu.be/c1gO9aB9nbs?si=3LG0CpVf1p5-AeRS). if I remember correctly it covers queue.

Comment: This code is wrong. Lets see `push`. One item in queue. Thread A start pushing. Thread A gets tail, meanwhile thread B pops and disposes item, thread A resumes execution and has dangling pointer is used `old_tail->next.compare_exchange_weak`

Comment: in general, use of a spin lock wouldn't be considered "lock-free"

Comment: Now I see this code simply leaks memory :/. It is not valid even without use of threads,

Comment: It is even worse. This doesn't even compile: https://godbolt.org/z/fvdqzhaM4 so it would be better if you ignore this article!

Comment: @MarekR I just read another article and saw the code, the enqueue method is a full page of code and it looks just as inefficient. I dunno, it seems all these claims of a lock-free anything isn't as good as simply testing and setting and then setting a variable/flag to false. And much much simpler.

Comment: Spin locking is not better than a lock-free algorithm if there is some non-negotiable project requirement that says a lock-free algorithm _must_ be used. IDK who would impose that requirement or why, but I do know that just because faster is better, that doesn't always mean that fastest is best. There may be other considerations (e.g., reliability, availability, et cetera-ility) besides just speed.

Comment: @SolomonSlow one common need for lock free code is predictably, it might not be the fastest method but it can avoid problems like priority inversion or starvation and can provide a consistent execution time. The unpredictability of locks can be a deal breaker in real time applications

Comment: Lock-free queues are (much!) easier to implement if they are of a fixed (maximum) size.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes but how about atomic_flag.lock(), myvector.push_back(item); atomic_flag.unlock()?

Comment: @PaulSanders If it's not possible to add to a list (in no particular order) in less than two atomic operations then I'm just doing it my way, lock the critical section with an atomic flag push into a vector and then unlock. Simple.

Comment: Re, "Yes but how about atomic_flag.lock()...?" Re-read @AlanBirtles comment (which probably should be an "answer," BTW). He cites some good, real-world reasons why a lock-free solution sometimes is better than using a lock. And, it's not about which one is faster or which one is easier to implement.